# get jquery ui slider value outside of callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

Is it possible to get the value of the handle of a [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) outside of the slide (or any) callback? I know you can get it inside the slide with ui.value, but how do I get that value from the outside everytime I move the slider?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check - http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#option-value

Read the value using `$( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" )` with the element id `slider-range-max`

Demo - http://fiddle.jshell.net/kyQZA/1/

Answer (score 1):

See [.slider()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#method-value) documentation and use `$('#the_element').slider("value")` to get the value.